# How do I physically replace an internal dual-boot hard-disk, without fresh OS reinstall?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, hard-drive

On dual boot Win XP SP3 || Lx Ubuntu 14.04 LTS aka Trusty, I need to upgrade my /dev/sda (disk 0) to a bigger disk. /dev/sda has 7 volumes (logical and extended partitions) and 2 OS (XP and Trusty). I do not want to reinstall everything fresh.

- Can I actually bit-copy /dev/sda to /dev/sdb, replace /dev/sda physically and copy the content of /dev/sdb back to the new /dev/sda ? Or do that via an ISO image ?
- Does it work at all ? Would any OS not balk at the new hardware found ?
  (/dev/sda will have changed and for instance I surmsise I would need to look carefully at my fstab after the fact because of the fact that partitions are referred to by their UUID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this without affecting my XP licence, using **parted** on Ubuntu.

It's not exactly what I did, but I would recommend using **dd** to do a disc-to-disc copy, swap the discs, then make sure everything boots on the new disc. Then swap back and use **parted** to move/resize the partitions on the new disc in order to use the extra space.

There are quicker ways to do it, but this conservative approach makes sure that keep the same partition labels, and you still have the original disc, so you do not lose anything.

Comment: AFH, Thank you. My concern is not about my Win license. I have all I need on that front. I am just looking for the best way of doing this. If dd actually preserve MBR, boot block, formating, etc, should I already format and partition the new hard drive with identical partition labels and all **before** starting the dd utility or does dd take care of partition and labels ?

Comment: One precision: using 'udisks', my partition table on the drive to be replaced, ie. /dev/sda, looks like: - /dev/sda1 NTFS 44GB Win XP - /dev/sda2 Ext3 500MB /boot - /dev/sda3 swap 8GB - /dev/sda5 Ext3 20GB / - /dev/sda6 Ext3 102GB /home - /dev/sda7 Ext3 13GB /var

Comment: Using **dd** on the whole disc (_/dev/sda_) will copy everything, MBR, boot sectors, partition structures, the lot. That's why I suggested doing this first. You will need to format the target first, but you need not create any partitions: any you do create will be overwritten by the copy. Be aware that because of different geometries partition boundaries, which may be aligned to cylinders on the old disc, will not necessarily be aligned on the new disc, but you can realign when you move/resize.

Answer (score 1):

My own detailed answer differs a little #1, or so it seems:

- Plug in/connect **Source** (if not internal) and **Target** devices, then

  ```
  > sudo lshw -C disk
  ```

  or

  ```
  > sudo fdisk -l
  ```

  or

  ```
  > lsblk -o name,label,size,fstype,model
  ```
- Note all necessary info, such as logical names (/dev/sda, ...) and serial numbers for both **Source** and **Target**.
- Boot from *Live Ubuntu*
- Check if you have ddrescue on yr *Live Ubuntu*. The package is actually called 'gddrescue', available on ppa:universe. Install gddrescue which does a better job at dealing with bad blocks than dd (dd is not equipped to deal with bad blocks):

  ```
  > sudo apt-get install gddrescue
  ```
- Use GParted to put an initial partition on the **TARGET** from *Live Ubuntu*
- (Make sure all devices are well identified and unmounted) An alternative to GParted is:

  ```
  > cfdisk -z  Target      # follow dialog (type w and accept)
  ```

  followed by

  ```
  > sudo ddrescue -v -r3 -d Source Target xyz.logfile bs=512k
  ```
- More info is available on ddrescue [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) and plenty examples for your unmitigated pleasure are out there in the web.
- Note that **Source** and **Target** can be whole disks or partitions.
- That's it. You're left with checking (use "e2fsck -fp Target" ) the soundness of your actions and you can swap disks.
- Put the **Target** in place of the **Source**, boot from it if it contains one or more OS (my case), then halt and power off.
- Boot again from *Live Ubuntu* and use GParted to modify partitions of the unmounted device to taste, in case the **Target** volume was bigger than the **Source** (my case).

end of story